# How to read information from an XML file in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, action

I need to build an XML file that is read by this code.
I can't figure out how to do it.

```
public function formDoneLoading(param1:ServerConfig) : void
{
    this.serverConfig = param1;
    this.loadAvatars("boy");
    this.loadAvatars("girl");
    this.hairXMLLoader = new URLLoader(new 
    URLRequest(this.avatarPath + "defaultHair.xml"));
    this.hairXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,this.hairXMLLoaded);
    //this.hairXMLLoader.load(); //# this part is missing in original code
    
}

private function hairXMLLoaded(param1:Event) : void
{
    var _loc2_:XML = XML(this.hairXMLLoader.data);
    this.BOY_INIT_HAIR = _loc2_.defaultHair.@boy;
    this.GIRL_INIT_HAIR = _loc2_.defaultHair.@girl;
}
```

[Is what I'm doing right? This is how you write the XML document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK9Nt.png)

My example XML:

[image]

Comment: You never start the actual loading. That's probably why it doesn't work as you expect it to. Also, **XML(...)** is type casting, you might want trying **new XML(...)** instead.

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't get an error, it just doesn't load the information that is inside the xml file

Comment: @JustMoon As I pointed out, you just **don't** load it.

Comment: Hi, Why not? If I don't load it, I'm missing parts in my flash game, and if I don't have it, I see a in developer toolbox error because the file doesn't exist

Comment: @JustMoon What he means is: If you have a `hairXMLLoader = new URLLoader` then you must also **begin the loading process** by using a `hairXMLLoader.load();`. Then the load complete event will trigger.

Comment: PS: You can try as: `this.hairXMLLoader = new URLLoader();` then do a `this.hairXMLLoader.load( new URLRequest(this.avatarPath + "defaultHair.xml") );`. That should work to trigger the "loading is complete" function.

Comment: Ok tanks, I try this

Comment: Hi, I tried as you told me and it didn't work.
How do I build the XML file according to the parameters it requests?

Comment: @VC.One I tried what you told me and it doesn't work

Comment: @Organis What do you recommend doing?

Comment: @JustMoon I advise to start with explaining, what are you trying to achieve. The "*I need to build*" is not a specific problem and does not explain anything.

Comment: @JustMoon **(1)** You need to update your question with what current code you've used. **(2)** Add actual text of XML (not untestable image). **(3)**. Not clear where your _"it doesn't work"_ is coming from. I mean does the function **hairXMLLoaded** actually run? If yes, what is the trace of **_loc2_** after updating that var? Is it your XML text? What is the trace of **this.BOY_INIT_HAIR** after updating it? **PS:** Explain your expected result, what should happen between `BOY_INIT_HAIR` and your XML (what to extract)?

Comment: @Organis I am missing an xml file that is responsible for errors in registering the avatars when the site loads them

Comment: @VC.One I don't really understand.. What I don't have the original file is a game from a time that was closed and I'm trying to play it, through the files

Comment: @JustMoon _"I don't really understand.."_ It's simple..., **(1)** You typed some code and you pressed the "test" button, right? Click [this text](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73597527/edit) to edit your question by pasting **the code you've tested today** so we can see what is your _"not working"_. **(2)** You see the picture? Where did the text come from? Go to that same place (or file, or app) and then cut/paste that XML text into your question (maybe someone can resave it as an XML for their own testing. No one can test the XML text if you show only pixels inside a picture).

Comment: @JustMoon **(3)** Do you know how to use `trace` option? Maybe have the first line of your **hairXMLLoaded** function as something like:  `trace("XML is loaded...");`. Check if the function is running by checking If that trace message is showing in the compiler console.

Comment: It's impossible to trace because I don't have the original file

Comment: @JustMoon I don't know what the original file has to do with this? Your question is how to read an XML, so **first try loading an XML file**. Make one using a text editor and save it with some name like **test.xml**, then make your code tries to load `test.xml`. Put the XML file in same place/folder as the SWF file. You will know it's loaded when the function `hairXMLLoaded ` is running. That's why you put a `trace` message in there to notify yourself when it runs. No XML loaded means no reading of anything else. If you cannot load a text/XML file in AS3, you're not ready to modify game code.

Comment: I have already created a file, everything is fine, I just want to know what values I put in the file? It shows me in the browser the file that I am accessing the Internet

Answer (score 1):

```js
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

XML.ignoreComments = false;
XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

public const FNAME:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "/myfile.xml");
public const FSTREAM:FileStream = new FileStream();
FSTREAM.open(FNAME, FileMode.READ);
var myxml:XML = new XML(<myxmlroot/>);
myxml = new XML(FSTREAM.readUTFBytes(FSTREAM.bytesAvailable));
FSTREAM.close();
```

Comment: Nice, but it won't work in browser.

Comment: @Organis you are right; this is a snippet for AIR SDK only